# Application of Residue Theorem to inverse Fourier transform

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I'm reading through a derivation in a book and am having trouble understanding a step. Here's a screenshot[image]

3.46 is the equation in $(k,\omega)$ space. They're doing an inverse Fourier transform back to $(k, t)$ space. I don't understand how they get the second term in 3.48. I'm pretty sure $\omega(k)$ are the roots of $D(k,\omega)$, and it seems like they're using the residue theorem, but how do they get the $\frac{\partial D(k,\omega)}{\partial \omega}$ in the denominator? I don't remember any derivatives appearing in the residue of a function.

Comment: they guess that $D(k,\omega)$ has a zero of order $1$ at $\omega(k)$ so that $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\frac{\partial D}{\partial \omega}(k;\omega(k))} = Res\left(\frac{1}{D(k;z)}, z= \omega(k)  \right)$  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Simple_poles note that this formula wouldn't be true if the zero was of order $2$ or more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $\frac{1}{D(k,\omega)(\omega-\omega_f)}$ has a simple pole at $\omega_k$.  Then, using L'Hospital's Rule, we have

$$\begin{align}
\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{D(k,\omega)(\omega-\omega_f)},\omega=\omega(k)\right)&=\lim_{\omega \to \omega(k)}\left((\omega-\omega(k))\frac{1}{D(k,\omega)(\omega-\omega_f)}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\left. \frac{\partial D(k,\omega)}{\partial \omega}\right|_{\omega=\omega(k)}(\omega(k)-\omega_f)}
\end{align}$$

since $D(k,\omega(k))=0$.

Comment: Oh okay thanks. That was easy.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure. - Mark